# UIWebView: как вести историю URL-адресов на ajax-сайтах?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ajax

Добрый день!
Ранее возникал [вопрос](http://toster.ru/q/73158) как обновлять кнопки браузера назад/вперед при посещении страниц ajax-сайтов (типа m.vk.com). Частично я решил эту проблему.
Теперь стоит задача как вести историю URL-адресов для кнопок назад/вперед когда для ajax-сайтов проблемно идентифицировать момент перехода и сам URL-адрес страницы.
В мобильном сафари это сделано. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Перетягиваем от кнопки ко UIWebView, думаю со скрина понятно будет:

[image]

Comment: И как это может помочь моей проблеме? Может не совсем понятен был вопрос... браузер готов почти и на обычных сайтах все работает и переходы назад/вперед и момент идентификации начала и конца загрузки страницы. Проблема именно с ajax-сайтами (типа m.vk.com)

Comment: Простите, был невнимателен, я с такой проблемой не сталкивался, я надеюсь, что Вы можете найти ответ тут (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105280/back-forward-buttons-for-uiwebview-cangoback-not-working-with-ajax-sites).

Comment: Гуглил конечно тоже и видел эту страничку. Там не нашел решения для своей проблемы.